# Unable to add the SCSS tag to a question

Tags: support, tags

I have recently come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801133/font-size-not-consistent-percentage?noredirect=1#comment44013213_27801133) question in which the OP had tagged with "css".

After realising the question was more to do with SCSS and SASS, I decided to edit the question to incorporate these tags.

On saving the edits, I found that only the SASS tag had applied, and not the "SCSS" tag.

I presumed it was an error on my part (it usually is), but again, adding the tag and saving did nothing - the tag didn't add.

Is this a problem with my side? Or just a little bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`scss` is a **synonym** for the [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass) tag. It is being remapped automatically.

See the [`sass` synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sass/synonyms).

Looking at the [`sass` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sass/info)  it may be time to invert that decision. SCSS seems to be the dominant dialect now, rather than SASS.

Comment: oh, ok, that makes sense now. Cheers for clearing that up for me.